# Lambda with consteval keyword leads to errors with GCC and MSVC while LLVM works. Who is right?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, c++20, clang++

I get errors with MSVC 19.33 and GCC 12.2 with the following code.

LLVM 16 (`clang++` with `libc++`) compiles it. [godbolt LLVM](https://godbolt.org/z/fhP1ovc1d)

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

int main() {
    static constexpr auto enlarge =
        [](std::string&& target, std::size_t const new_size) consteval {
            auto const old_size = target.size();
            if(new_size < old_size) {
                throw "new size is smaller then old size";
            }
            target.resize(new_size);
            target[old_size] = 0;
            return target.c_str();
        };

    using namespace std::literals;
    static_assert(enlarge("test"s, 32) == "test"sv);
}
```

GCC 12.2 (`g++` & `libstdc++`) complains: [godbolt GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/EW7a8z5d1)

```
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/string:41,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/allocator.h: In function 'int main()':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/allocator.h:185:52: error: 'enlarge.main()::<lambda(std::string&&, std::size_t)>(std::literals::string_literals::operator""s(const char*, std::size_t)(4), 32)' is not a constant expression because it refers to a result of 'operator new'
  185 |             return static_cast<_Tp*>(::operator new(__n));
      |                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

MSVC 19.33 complains: [MS godbolt MSVC](https://www.godbolt.ms/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:19,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:19,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:19,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:19),source:%27%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring_view%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++static+constexpr+auto+enlarge+%3D%0A++++++++%5B%5D(std::string%26%26+target,+std::size_t+const+new_size)+consteval+%7B%0A++++++++++++auto+const+old_size+%3D+target.size()%3B%0A++++++++++++if(new_size+%3C+old_size)+%7B%0A++++++++++++++++throw+%22new+size+is+smaller+then+old+size%22%3B%0A++++++++++++%7D%0A++++++++++++target.resize(new_size)%3B%0A++++++++++++target%5Bold_size%5D+%3D+0%3B%0A++++++++++++return+target.c_str()%3B%0A++++++++%7D%3B%0A%0A++++using+namespace+std::literals%3B%0A++++static_assert(enlarge(%22test%22s,+32)+%3D%3D+%22test%22sv)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_33_arm64,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27/std:c%2B%2Blatest%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27arm64+msvc+v19.33+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27),(h:output,i:(compilerName:%27arm64+msvc+v19.28+VS16.9%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+arm64+msvc+v19.33+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:1,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
<source>(17): error C7595: 'main::<lambda_1>::operator ()': call to immediate function is not a constant expression
<source>(17): note: (sub-)object points to memory which was deallocated during constant evaluation
<source>(17): error C2446: '==': no conversion from 'std::string_view' to 'int'
<source>(17): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

If I remove the keyword `consteval` from the lambda, it works on all three Compilers with there corresponding standard libraries. ([LLVM](https://godbolt.org/z/Mqrv5oKzh), [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/r5GWbhdq5), [MSVC](https://www.godbolt.ms/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:61,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:61,positionLineNumber:6,selectionStartColumn:61,selectionStartLineNumber:6,startColumn:61,startLineNumber:6),source:%27%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring_view%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++static+constexpr+auto+enlarge+%3D%0A++++++++%5B%5D(std::string%26%26+target,+std::size_t+const+new_size)+%7B%0A++++++++++++auto+const+old_size+%3D+target.size()%3B%0A++++++++++++if(new_size+%3C+old_size)+%7B%0A++++++++++++++++throw+%22new+size+is+smaller+then+old+size%22%3B%0A++++++++++++%7D%0A++++++++++++target.resize(new_size)%3B%0A++++++++++++target%5Bold_size%5D+%3D+0%3B%0A++++++++++++return+target.c_str()%3B%0A++++++++%7D%3B%0A%0A++++using+namespace+std::literals%3B%0A++++static_assert(enlarge(%22test%22s,+32)+%3D%3D+%22test%22sv)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_33_arm64,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27/std:c%2B%2Blatest%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27arm64+msvc+v19.33+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27),(h:output,i:(compilerName:%27arm64+msvc+v19.28+VS16.9%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+arm64+msvc+v19.33+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:1,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4))

Is this a bug in GCC and MSVC or does `consteval` have another effect on the execution than the call in a `constexpr` context and LLVM is wrong to accept that?

---

I assume this is a separate issue here, but for completeness: When I run `clang++` 16 with `libstdc++` 12.2 I get regardless of `consteval` the error: [godbolt clang++ with libstdc++](https://godbolt.org/z/zbWxMxb7Y)

```
<source>:17:19: error: static assertion expression is not an integral constant expression
    static_assert(enlarge("test"s, 32) == "test"sv);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:620:2: note: undefined function '_M_construct<const char *>' cannot be used in a constant expression
        _M_construct(__s, __s + __n, std::forward_iterator_tag());
        ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:4330:14: note: in call to 'basic_string(&"test"[0], 4, std::allocator<char>())'
    { return basic_string<char>{__str, __len}; }
             ^
<source>:17:27: note: in call to 'operator""s(&"test"[0], 4)'
    static_assert(enlarge("test"s, 32) == "test"sv);
                          ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:330:9: note: declared here
        _M_construct(_FwdIterator __beg, _FwdIterator __end,
        ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the changes made by [P2564R3](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2564r3.html) to the current C++23 draft, the code is well-formed, because `enlarge("test"s, 32)` is not an *immediate invocation* as it is a subexpression of a *manifestly constant-evaluated expression* (the operand of `static_assert`).

However, without that change, MSVC and GCC are correct to reject the code and Clang is wrong to accept it. Without the change `enlarge("test"s, 32)` is an immediate invocation and immediate invocations form full-expressions. That means temporary objects created during their evaluation are destroyed as the last step of the evaluation.

Consequently the temporary object that `target` refers to is destroyed as the last step of evaluating `enlarge("test"s, 32)`. However you are returning a pointer into this object with `return target.c_str();`. The immediate invocation must be a *constant expression*, but an invalid pointer is not a permitted result of a *constant expression*.

This is what MSVC and GCC are complaining about. Both error messages complain specifically about returning a pointer to deallocated memory, but the same should hold if there was no dynamic memory allocation involved, e.g. because SSO was sufficient.